# What is the "true" entropy of a binary string?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, information-theory, entropy

Consider an infinite binary string $\sigma$ and define its [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29)

$$H_1 = -(p_0 \log_2 p_0 + p_1 \log_2 p_1)$$

with $p_i = \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} N(i)/N$, $N(i)$ the number of $i$'s among the first $N$ digits.

Now consider the very same string as composed of words $w$ of length $n$ and define the corresponding entropies

$$H_n = -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{w \in \lbrace 0,1\rbrace^n} p_w \log_2 p_w $$

A natural [candidate](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropie_%28Informationstheorie%29#Definition) for the "true" entropy of $\sigma$ might be

$$H = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} H_n$$

Note, that for a truly random string $H_n = H = 1$. For a higly regular string like $0101010\dots$ we have $H_1 = 1, H_n = H = 0$ for $n\geq 2$.

> **Question 1**: Is every value $0 \leq H \leq 1$ possible? Are there sequences which don't reach the limit?
>
> **Question 2**: Which progressions of $H_n$ are conceivable? Does it have to be a monotonic sequence, or can it oscillate?
>
> **Question 3**: Under which assumptions does this limit exist?

Now consider *finite* binary strings $\sigma$ of length $N$. Here we have $H_n = 0$ for $n > N/2$ and $H_{N/2}$ can only take the values $0$ or $1$.

> **Question 4**: What is a natural candidate for the "true" entropy of *finite* binary strings?

Comment: You may want to look up entropy rates.

Comment: Your notation is confusing. $H_1$ can mean two things...can you fix it?